# How do I check if an object is moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to do something in unity, And I need to know if the camera is moving or not.

This is the script:

```
GameObject MainCamara = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera");
NewPosition = new Vector3(player.position.x, player.position.y, -10);
positionChanging(NewPosition);
if (MainCamara.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>() == null)
{
        CameraMoving = true;
}
if (MainCamara.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.magnitude > 0.01f)
{
    CameraMoving = true;
}
CameraMoving = false;
```

I am not getting any errors, but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store your Camera tansform.position in a Vector3 during execution of Update() function. The next time Update is triggered just compare position you've stored from the previous Update execution with your current Camera's position. If they're not the same, that means camera is in move. Code would look something as follows

```
Vector3 prevCamPos;

void Update() {
    bool cameraInMove = prevCamPos != MainCamera.transform.position;
    if(cameraInMove) { /* do sth */ }
    prevCamPos = MainCamera.transform.position;

    // ... some logic
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider using:

```
Camera.main.velocity
```

From [Unity Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-velocity.html)